# How copy a file stored as largeobject in postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I use postgres 9.3 as DB, Spring 4.0.6 and the postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar driver.
I have the code to store a File into DB with the LargeObjectManager. 
I have also the code to retrieve the data with the LargeObjectManager.
This works fine.

Now I need to copy the file.

My theory is I can reuse the two pieces of code over there to retrieve first the old File, and then rewrite it with a new oid.

But my question is: already exists a such function on the drivers?

I have seen That there are also a CopyManager, but I'm not really sure if I can use it for largeObject.

Has anyone a better suggestion that mine to copy a largeObject?

Comment: CopyManager is *not* for large objects, it's for the `COPY` command for bulk loading / extracting rows. One option would be to `lo_export` to a server-side tempfile then `lo_import` that tempfile.

Comment: Txs Craig. I unfortunately I don't want export any file on file system. Because this is a security risk. Everyone can watch on the directory and make a copy of them. This is not admitted for our software. Have you an other suggestion?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to use `loread` and `lowrite` to copy blocks of the object within a PL/PgSQL procedure, probably.

Comment: Out of interest ... why do you need to copy it? are you planning on modifying it in-place?

Comment: Nothing on the fly. The feature is only to give a functionality to make a copy of an existing stored file on the DB. Why? Can this help to have other options?

Comment: Well, if you're not modifying the file, why copy it at all? Just copy the oid, so you have multiple references to the one large object.

Comment: Ok, that can be a good point. Question: what happens when i make a lo_unlink with this oid? Then I lose the reference on both. Right?

Comment: Correct, yes. You'd need to refcount via an indirection table. Also look into the `lo` extension and `vacuumlo`.